# using trigger to update particular column with current_timestamp it says trigger created but do not update

Tags: sql

```
create or replace trigger trg1
before
insert on patient
referencing old as old new as new
 for each row
 begin
 if inserting then
     update patient set p_join_date = current_timestamp where :old.patient_id= null;
 end if;
end;
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific, so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `update`:

```
update patient
    set p_join_date = current_timestamp
    where :old.patient_id = null;
```

The `where` *never* evaluates to true, so no rows will ever be updated.  Presumably you intent:

```
update patient
    set p_join_date = current_timestamp
    where :old.patient_id is null;
```